# Backup Failed. Error: g-io-error-quark:

Tags: backup

I have set up Ubuntu 16.04 to back up some folders to an external Seagate hard drive and it had been working fine but this morning the Back Up program gave the following message:

```
Backup Failed. Giving up after 5 attempts. 
Error:g-io-error-quark:Can't recursively copy directory(25)
```

[image: Error Dialog]

Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Start with `find . -name 'g-io-quark' -ls` . Is the directory linked to itself?

Comment: I do: $ sudo find . -name 'g-io-quark' -ls and the terminal returns this : find: './run/user/1000/gvfs' : Permission denied. If I don't do sudo, then there are probably over a hundred Permission denied messages.

Comment: Ignore, for now, the error messages `sudo find . -name 'g-io-quark' -ls 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Pi-clone has started giving a similar error so I ended up here by googling.  It also doesn't read its source and destination devices.  I'll create an issue in the project's space on Github.  The issue is bigger than either Ubuntu or Pi-clone.[image]